# Extract a number from a string which precedes a phrase in R

Tags: r

I am in R and would like to extract a two digit number `38y` from the following string:

```
"/Users/files/folder/file_number_23a_version_38y_Control.txt"
```

I know that `_Control` always comes after the `38y` and that `38y` is preceded by an underscore. How can I use `strsplit` or other R commands to extract the `38y`?

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```r
library(stringr)

text <- "/Users/files/folder/file_number_23a_version_38y_Control.txt"

str_extract(text, "(?<=_)\\d+\\D(?=_Control)")

#> [1] "38y"
```

You can find an explanation of the regex part at:

https://regex101.com/r/PQSZHX/1

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```r
regmatches(x, regexpr("[^_]+(?=_Control)", x, perl = TRUE))
# [1] "38y"
```

or equivalently

```r
stringr::str_extract(x, "[^_]+(?=_Control)")
# [1] "38y"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `gsub`.

```
gsub('.*_(.*)_Control.*', '\\1', x)
# [1] "38y"
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/JBsXVW/1) with detailed explanation.